# unable to load the data to html file from a text file called sample.txt using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text file called sample.txt and I want to load the data of that file using following HTML file but it would not be loading.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery.get('sample.txt', function(theData) {
    alert(theData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Alert data from text file</h1>
<div><p id="fileData"></p></div>
```

Comment: Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: If you're running this under the local file system you'll be blocked by browser security. You'll need to run the AJAX request on a webserver. You can easily install one on your local machine, though

Comment: you need to make sure your server is serving the file... try doing this http://servername/sample.txt in browser and see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running locally this can cause errors: [image: Error while running locally.]

See [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Running the HTML code using XAMPP and calling localhost it works without error. 
`JQuery.get...` is not working using `file:///` protocol.